# Is there a typescript or javascript api for Geolocation - Get IP to Location Preview capability in the Azure Maps npm module azure-maps-rest

Tags: azure-maps

There are a lot of options to this api and I am not finding this capability in the module? If it is not in there can it be added in the future?

The [preview is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/geolocation/getiptolocationpreview)

The [typescript API is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-rest/atlas.service.searchurl?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest)

Comment: If you are looking for a Typescript library that links with an IP geolocation service, I suggest giving a try to Ipregistry: https://github.com/ipregistry/ipregistry-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently. The services module wraps a subset of the services currently based on priority/popularity. Also there are some planned improvements to the geolocation API, so have been waiting for that.

Using this API from the browser is pretty easy though as you simply append the IP address and your subscription key to the service URL and use the fetch API in the browser to download the results. Here is a code block:

```js
interface IpToLocationResponse {
    ipAddress: string;
    countryRegion: IpToLocationCountry;
    error: IpToLocationError;
}

interface IpToLocationCountry {
    isoCode: string
}

interface IpToLocationError {
    code: string;
    message: string;
}

public ipToLocation(subscriptionKey, ipAddress): Promise<IpToLocationResponse> {

    var request = `https://atlas.microsoft.com/geolocation/ip/json?subscription-key=${subscriptionKey}&api-version=1.0&ip=${ipAddress}`;

    return fetch(request)
    .then(r => {
        return r.json();
    });
}
```

Comment: are these interfaces you made or are available? Also, why doen't the IP allow for location directly down to at least the zipcode or POI array. Do you work for MSFT?

Comment: Yes, I work for Microsoft (in my profile). Currently this service is country level, but a high resolution option is planned.

Comment: I am going to implement this today. 1 Thing that in the azure bot service for some reason the map search service that has a npm package fails when deploying it to the azure web service. But not locally. So I am going to bring this over to a service too.